# How can I add a menu in my magento backend?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml

Below is my code for my menu and it does not work on my side.

**config.xml**

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MasteringMagento_Example>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </MasteringMagento_Example>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <example>
           <class>MasteringMagento_Example_Model</class> 
        </example>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <example>
            <class>MasteringMagento_Example_Block</class>
        </example>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <example>
            <class>MasteringMagento_Example_Helper</class>
        </example>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

**adminhtml.xml**

```
<config>
<menu>
    <example translate="title" module="example">
        <title>Example</title>
        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
        <action>adminhtml/example</action>
    </example>
</menu>
```

Comment: why are you creating duplicate question again? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/how-to-add-menu-to-magento-backend

Comment: because i don't know the answer.

Comment: will you get answer if you create duplicate question?

Comment: can you please add full code of both the files?

Answer (score 0):

You know, the admin menu contains a lot of files, I'll not put all the module files, but I will help you to direct you to the right solution.

**app/code/local/MasteringMagento/Example/etc/config.xml**

```
...
</global>    
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <example>
                <file>example.xml</file>
            </example>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/MasteringMagento/Example/etc/adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
        <menu>
            <menu1 module="example" translate="title">
                <title>Menu 1</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <item1 module="example" translate="title">
                        <title>Submenu 1</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/menu/index</action>
                    </item1>
                    <item2 module="example" translate="title">
                        <title>Submenu 2</title>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/index/index</action>
                    </item2>
                </children>
            </menu1>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <menu1 translate="title" module="example">
                            <title>Menu 1</title>
                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <item1 translate="title">
                                    <title>Submenu 1</title>
                                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                </item1>
                                <item2 translate="title">
                                    <title>Submenu 2</title>
                                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                                </item2>
                            </children>
                        </menu1>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </config>
```

**app/code/local/MasteringMagento/Example/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php**

```
<?php

class MasteringMagento_Example_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('menu/menu')
            ->_title($this->__('Submenu1'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/example.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="exemple/adminhtml_menu" name="exemple"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_index_index>
</layout>
```

Now you have to create **all files block** ...