# Create a custom menu in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to create a menu in admin dashboard , just like sales , products and my menu structure will be parent->child .Any one can hep me to do this.

Comment: see this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/191651/91726)

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: I have created a menu and now I am trying to create a grid and controller. Is there any link.

Comment: Can you please mention , How I will create a grid and link it to my controller.

Comment: Although, I work on Magento 2 but this [link](https://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/) may help you in your work.